# inner divs do not get vertically centered or left aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Divs inside a container div do neither get vertically centered nor left aligned for me.

The desired layout is basically a close box left of a content box. To achieve this, close and content box each reside in their own div. These two divs are children of a flex display div with left horizontal item alignment (`justify-content: flex-start`) and vertical aligment top (`align-items:start`). That flex display div is child of a general container flex display div with left horizontal alignment and centered vertical aligment. The dimensions of the (outermost) general container is given in vw, vh (--> relative).

See the below code.

However, the inner divs always get horizontally centered, so when I increase the window width, the general container gets wider, and the content inside it moves right to stay centered.

Please help me to fix this.

STYLE:

```
.content-area {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 2vw;  
    top: 10vh;  
    width: 30vw;  
    height: 80vh;  
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;  
    align-items: center;  
    justify-content: flex-start;  
    }  

.content-control {  
    position: relative;  
    margin: 0 0 0 0;  
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: row;  
    align-items: start;  
    justify-content: flex-start;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    background-color: #808080;  
    }

#content-data {  
    position: relative;  
    margin: 2vh 0 2vh 0;  
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;  
    align-items: center;  
    justify-content: center;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    }  

.close-btn-area {  
    margin: 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin;  
    width: 4vh;  
    height: 4vh;  
    display: flex;  
    align-items: start;  
    justify-content: right;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -khtml-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;  
    -o-user-select: none;  
    -ms-user-select: none;  
    user-select: none;  
    }  

#info-content {  
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', Verdana, sans-serif;  
    font-variant: small-caps;  
    color:#404040;  
    background-color: #a0a0a0;  
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content-area" id="info-area">  
    <div class="content-control" id="info-control">  
        <div class="close-btn-area" id="close-info">
            <img class="close-btn" 
                 id="close-btn-info" 
                 src="images/close-btn-inverted-128x128.png">
         </div>
         <div class="content-data" id="info-data">  
                <article id="info-content">  
                </article>  
         </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

For a quick visual impression, open http://www.descent2.de/S/index.html and click on the second link from top ("Schmücken"). I have given varying background colors to each div (except the close box):

- black: general container
- dark gray: container to align close box div left of text box div
- light gray: text box div

Make the browser window wide enough and you will start to see how the close and text box get centered instead of staying left.

Comment: try this : .content-area { width: 50vw}  is that what  are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightpink;
}

.content-area {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
}

.content-control {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #808080;
}

#content-data {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2vh 0 2vh 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.close-btn-area {
  margin: 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin;
  width: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#info-content {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #404040;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content-area" id="info-area">
    <div class="content-control" id="info-control">
      <div class="close-btn-area" id="close-info">
        <button class="close-btn" id="close-btn-info">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content-data" id="info-data">
        <article id="info-content">
          <h1>decorate</h1>
          <p>Why decorate? What does decorate mean? How to decorate? Beauty is a value in itself. Decorating is always a highlight for me, a highlighting of the </p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When using `flex-direction: column`, `justify-content` acts on the vertical axis and `align-*` on the horizontal. So, it was being horizontally centered and placed at the top of the flexbox. Does that answer your question?

It is noted here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction (though how it's stated is arguably opaque - I'm not sure why they don't just say x and y axis)

Comment: Thank you. I already got it working with the hints given before you posted.

Answer (score 1):

From whatever I understood from your question is you would like to align 
`<div class="content-control">...</div>` vertically centered and horizontally left w.r.to parent div `<div class="content-area">...</div>`
If that's what you're looking for, please update your CSS properties for class 'content-area' as showing below:

```
.content-area {
justify-content: center;
align-item: left;
}
```

Comment: I think you got it the wrong way round. justify-content aligns horizontally and align-item aligns vertically acc. to all I have read on the inet.

Comment: Yes, but as you're using flex-direction: column, it works opposite way.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `flex-direction: column;`, so `align-items: center;` will affect the *horizontal* alignment of the children (i.e. center them horizontally) and `justify-content: flex-start;` will affect the *vertical* alignment of the children.

Change `align-items: center;` to `align-items: flex-start;` to prevent the described unwanted horizontal centering.

Comment: I did this and the funny thing is that it works for a 2nd content box, but still not for the first one. Both areas are constructed almost identically. The one working is slightly more complex (it has an additional, innermost div). You can see that one when clicking on "Schmuck" at the website I linked to in my question.